# AJAX Call Prompting Up the "Print Page" Option

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax

Answered in the comments by John Tyner! Thank you! It's the prints in the success and error sections of the AJAX call.

I have a dropdown that on change, calls an AJAX function, which just stores the dropdown value into the session (this is not the issue, I've commented it out and same issue occurs), and when this AJAX function comes back successfully, it seems to prompt up the Print Page feature. I do not want it to prompt up the Print Page, and I can't seem to stop it from popping up.

Dropdown and AJAX fnc:

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <b><label>Choose settings from existing project:</label></b>
                            <select class="form-control" id="ProjectSelect">
                              <option selected="selected" disabled value=0> Select a setting </option>
                              {% for sID in settingsInfo %}
                              <option value="{{ sID.1 }}">
                                {{sID.0}}
                              </option>
                              {% endfor %}
                              <option value=0> None </option>
                            </select>
  
                            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
                            <script>
                              $('#ProjectSelect').on('change', function () {
                                var units = {
                                  dropdownValue: $(this).val()
                                };
  
                                $.ajax({
                                  url: 'ajax_settings_dropdown',
                                  async: true,
                                  data: units,
                                  success: function () {
                                    print("SUCCESS");
                                  },
                                  error: function () {
                                    print("Oops");
                                  }
                                });
  
                              });
                            </script>
```

views.py:

```
def update_settings_dropdown(request, project_id, groups_num):
    dropdownValue = request.GET.get('dropdownValue')

    if dropdownValue != 0: 
        currG_sID = request.session.get('createdGroups_sID')
        currG_sID.append(dropdownValue)
        request.session['createdGroups_sID'] = currG_sID
    return render(request, 'EmptyPage.html')
```

urls.py

```
path('app/newgroup/<str:project_id>/<str:groups_num>/ajax_settings_dropdown', views.update_settings_dropdown)
```

Comment: Not sure what the question was...

Comment: I do not want the Print Page to be prompted.

Comment: Why do you have `print("SUCCESS");` and `print("Oops");` - those just calling `window.print()` which is causing the print dialog to come up

Comment: Wow. I actually can't believe that went over my head. Boy do I love you right now. Thank you!